# how to get the Border from the hover effect inside the content

Tags: html, css, hover

hey guys i build here a nice hover effect on a profile card, but i would like to have the border that i have on the hover effect more inside the content. `padding` didnt worked for me, any clue how to fix it.

i have here a demo code of it on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8CcztJvNpq)

[image]

thats what im looking fore

```
.model-card {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0em 0.7em 1.4em 0.7em;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: box-shadow .25s;
    width: 15em;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: transform 0.3s ease-out; 
}

span.hover-content {
    background: rgba(135,211,183,0.7);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 21em;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

Comment: solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this css:

```
span.hover-content span {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `box-shadow`

```
span.hover-content span {

  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #777, 1px 1px #777;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```